# How to I fix mongodb community status error 12288

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, homebrew

I am not able to connect to MongoDb on my machine. When I check my brew services list I get a mongodb-community status error 12288.

When I try to start my server I get this error:

```
/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847
  const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                          
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:32)
    at /Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10
    at /Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/config/connection.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/daniel_zamanillo/Desktop/vandy/target-shopping/server/server.js:7:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
          name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        },
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 432291066,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: []
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
Node.js v17.3.0
```

My connection.js fils is the following

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/holiday-chaos-db",
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.connection;
```

My server is the following

```
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const path = require("path");

const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require("./schemas");
const { authMiddleware } = require("./utils/auth");
const db = require("./config/connection");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

startServer = async () => {
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        context: authMiddleware,
    });
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    console.log(`Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
};

startServer();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// Serve up static assets
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
}

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
});

db.once("open", () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
    });
});
```

I am used brew uninstall to remove all traces of mongosh, mongodb-community and mongodb-database-tools then used the install guide at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

When I run `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0` my terminal returns
`` Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community) `` but when I check my services list with `brew services list` my terminal returns

```
Name              Status       User             File
mongodb-community error  12288 daniel_zamanillo ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
php               none
php@7.4           none
```

I am at a bit of a loss here and would love some help to be able to connect to mongo again. Thank you!

Comment: Is your mongodb listening on IPv6 or only on IPv4?

Answer (score 1):

I believe its due to MongoDB (mongod) trying to write its log file to a location it does not have permission to write to.

First figure out where your `mongod.conf` file is (should be under `/usr/local`)

Inside that log file you want to look for your `mongo.log` file path location and update it to somewhere in your home directory.

Restart the service and it should work.

Comment: Thank you Gaza. I got it to work by uninstalling MongoDB@5.0 and reverting everything back to @4.2. I am going to be checking out those files you mentioned. Thanks again!